# JQuery Mobile Empty Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I'm currently creating a mobile website. I'm using jquery mobile.
I've already implemented the login and I'm now working on the registration.

On the login page i've got a simple `<a href="registration.html"></a>`. On the registration I am then logging the inputs, but it seems that the fields "username" and "password" are empty, even though i've entered some text. This problem doesn't occur after refreshing the page or if I load the page directly from the address bar.

Pageinit is being triggered.

I've deleted the cache but the problem is still there. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here my code:

```
<!-- PAGE LOGIN -->
    <div data-role="page" id="pageregistration">

        <div data-role="content">

            <input name="username" id="username" type="text" size="45" maxlength="45" placeholder="Username">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="text" size="45" maxlength="45" placeholder="Email">
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="45" maxlength="45" placeholder="Password">
            <input name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" type="password" size="45" maxlength="45" placeholder="Confirm Password">

            <button id="register">Create Account</button>


        </div>


        <script>

            $('#pageregistration').on('pageinit', function()
            {
                $("#register").click(function(e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;;
                    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    var passwordConfirm = document.getElementById('passwordConfirm').value;


                    console.log("Username: " + username + ", email: " + email + ", password: " + password + " - " + passwordConfirm);

                });
            });

        </script>

    </div>
```

Comment: make sure you're not using same ID's somewhere else in same _document_ (other pages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found thanks to [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar). I changed the IDs and everything worked as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this because `pageinit` is triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs.

Means you are getting to the registration page from somewhere (Other page)

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageregistration", function(event) {
//  rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. The values for "username" and "password" are still empty.
My Log is still: "Username: , email: example@asd.com, password:  - asd"

Comment: pageinit is triggered, otherwise the values wouldn't be logged. Just two of the values can't be read. I've entered a text, but the variables are empty